# Debugging empty results when using the Google Calendar API library for PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-workspace

I am building a feature for a PHP Symfony app that will update calendar events in a Google Calendar upon changes in my database on my server. The calendar belongs to the google account info@my-domain.com which I administer (domain just illustrative).

I am following the [instructions for the google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) in combination with the [example for using this library with the calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php).

Since this is *not* a multiuser scenario but pure server-to-server communication I opted for a service account on the Google Cloud Platform.
I created a project while logged in as info@my-domain.com and a service account. I downloaded the credentials.json for that service account. I enabled the Google Calendar API.

Now to the problem:

When I use this library this way:

```php
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('/config/google_api_keys.json');
$client->addScope(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
        
$cal_service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$results = $cal_service->calendarList->listCalendarList()->getItems();
dump($results);  //basically a fancy symfony-version of print_r()
die();
```

the code throws no errors but the variable `$results` is *empty* even though it should contain 3 calendars.

Yet when I use the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/) while being logged in as info@my-domain.com the result of the same operation (`GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList`) contains the 3 items I am looking for.

Just to check, I tried instead to use the PHP library to get the events for one of the 3 calendars using its id `s2b[...]e81@group.calendar.google.com`, but Google responded with 404-json containing "Not found".

One caveat with the API Explorer is that it only allows for login with OAuth 2.0 so seeing what might be wrong with a service account is not possible.

Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong? Or what I should try next? Or what concept I might have misunderstood when using the API?

Answer (score 1):

## possible cause for your issue one

Remember that listCalendarList is not automatically populated if you want a calendar to appear in listCalendarList then your going to have to insert it there.  I suggest trying to do a listCalendarList.insert and trying to add the calendar id that you gave it access to.

If that returns an error then see possible cause for issue number to

## possible cause for your issue two

I assume that you have set up [domain wide deligation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/domain#accessing_domain_calendars_as_an_app) but you forgot to set which user you are delegating as you do that by setSubject

```
function initializeCalendar()
{

  // Use the developers console and download your service account
  // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
  // change the key file location if necessary.
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';
  $user_to_impersonate ="user@domain.com";
  // Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Hello Calendar");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']);
  $client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);
  $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

  return $service;
}
```

Without setting up delegation the service account does not have access to any calendars.

Comment: Thank you, these where valuable hints! Regarding the first issue: These 3 calenders I am expecting to see are pre-existing, i.e. I manually created them. Why would the API Explorer be able to see them? I logged in as info@my-domain.com.
Regarding the second issue: I had already checked "Enable G Suite Domain-wide delegation" just to be sure. But when I set "$client->setSubject('info@my-domain.com');" the response becomes instead "Error: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested." Weird.

Comment: Error: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method  <--- go to google developer console and create service account credentials you created some other type. https://youtu.be/asrCdWFrF0A

Comment: **3 calendars I am expecting to see are pre-existing, i.e. I manually created them. Why would the API Explorer be able to see them?**  Manually created and API explorer can see them implies that you created them from your own personal calendar account.  A service account is NOT you. It is a dummy user, sharing that calendar with the service account will not automatically add it to the service accounts calendarlistlist.   THe web UI added it to your calendarlistlist because the webUI is designed to do that. It is not designed to add it to the user of the service account.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. You just gained a subscriber :-) Your video is exactly what I did previously, absolutely no difference. 
One obvious source of confusion could be that neither the project nor the user info@my-domain.com are part of any paid plan (G Suite/workspace). This might explain the "client is unauthorized..." error when using setSubject(). It seems like delegation only works if the project is part of the GSuite.

Comment: My original question assumed that there is a way to let my web app edit the events of a calendar owned by a simple google user *without* any paid plan. Google's documentation is extremely unclear about what is a paid-only feature and what works with free accounts.

Comment: Disregard my previous 2 comments. Your last comment was the one that created the AHA-moment. See my own answer below. Big thanks from Sweden to Denmark :-)

Comment: @fridde I literally just recorded a video explaining service accounts because your not the first one to be confused.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, with the help of @daimto I could come to a *very* simple solution:

I had to actually **share** the calendar owned by `info@my-domain.com` with the service account by adding its email address `abc-123@my-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com` in the calendar settings, just like I'd share this calendar with any other physical person like `eric@gmail.com`.

So my understanding of what a service account actually is was seriously flawed. I thought that it would be the co-owner of any resource (docs, spreadsheets, calendars, etc) that project's owner owned.

WRONG: `info@my-domain.com` owns the project `my-project-name` which "owns" the service account `abc-123@my-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and therefore the service account owns "everything".

(MORE) RIGHT: The service account acts rather like a virtual user that first has to get access to any resource that it's supposed to be working with. The access sharing can be done like you would add a friend to a resource or via an API.